# SQL Server 2012 Replication web synchronisation snapshot failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication

We're trying to build a new enviroment which replicates our existing setup. We're using sql server 2012 sp3, old servers were windows server 2008 new ones are 2016.  One server works fine, but the issue we have with the new environment is that when we create a snapshot and a subscriber connects via web synchronisation then the IIS worker process uses 16GB of ram and brings the server to it's knees and it all falls over. One of our BCP files is 4gb, if I put a filter on that table to only include a single record it all works. So I'm guessing the file size is coming into play here.

There isn't any meaningful error message coming from anywhere - other than windows killing the process when the ram spikes. What I don't understand is that in delivering the snapshot, it's not really doing anything other than streaming out the file contents.

Has anyone encountered this before? One idea would be try and split the BCP files into small chunks but I can find anyway of making that work.

Edit: So, it turns out the issue is now affecting our live environment too... It's just that the file size only creeped over the 4GB limit as of last week so we were to yet to run a snapshot.

So it seems that web synchronisation can't cope with BCP files > 4GB in size... Anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: To add: I'm now certain if the BCP file <4gb it all works, >4GB and it fails.. I've tried with various filtering options but it seems like whenever it hits a BCP file greater than 4GB it spins into a memory consuming loop..

Comment: That's a frickin' huge file to have to bulk import, though. At that point I'd seriously look at initializing replication from a backup, bypassing snapshots altogether. This is likely to be faster too, unless of course your non-replicated data is even *bigger*.

Comment: Yup... It was somewhat smaller when we went live 10+ years ago... Unfortunately, it was the web sync we want to use, with weekly snapshots and merge replication inbetween... I guess we could look at scripting the backup and copy the file over ftp or something...